# Computer Desktop icon for 13.04

Tags: 13.04, icons, shortcuts

I know that ubuntu 13.04 doesn't have a "Computer" icon for Desktop anymore,isn't there a way to make a shortcut for it tough? Googled a few days back and I know I saw a tutorial somewhere but I cannot find it anymore?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak is your friend.

Comment: Actually Ubuntu Tweak is not my friend in this matter. It crashes on 13.04 everytime I want to add a Computer icon.

Comment: You have installed 13.04?

Comment: im sorry for that comment. it isnt working for me. but it doesnt crash either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried Ubuntu Tweak, and it sure doesn't work.  So I found this [site](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-nautilus-34-features-back-in-ubuntu.html), so I tried, and it works.

Note: after you do the command `killall nautilus` start it by typing `sudo nautilus`.  After the window opens go ahead close it, and then close terminal.  That's what I had to do.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new .desktop file. Let's call it `Computer.desktop`
Now, use Gedit or some editor and enter the following in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Computer
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window /
Icon=system
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
Actions=Window;
```

Save the file. Now right click on the file, choose `Properties->Permissions`
Check the box to `Allow executing the file as a program`. And you have yourself a launcher for Computer.
If you want to change the location where the window starts, just change the `/` on line to the location where you want it to open.

Comment: This is pretty awesome :) great +1

Answer (score 1):

1.Open Unity (press super key.i.e. key having windows logo)

2.Make it smaller.i.e. exit full screen mode

3.search for files

4.Select the file icon and drag it to desktop

5.Open Text Editor(search for Text Editor in unity)

6.In Text Editor Click open and navigate to desktop

7.Select nautilus.desktop and open it.

8.Now just change Name to Computer from files and change the icon to system from system-file-manager

9.Save it and exit.

Now you have a computer icon on Desktop

Tried it in Ubuntu 13.04 not sure for other versions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you need classic menu in Unity you can use classic menu indicator applet, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

[image]

Else you can open application via unity dash:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Computer Icon

To show the Computer icon run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop computer-icon-visible true
```

To hide the Computer icon run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop computer-icon-visible false
```

Run this in Terminal